# Generator function does not yield proper value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, koa, iojs

I have recently learned a bit of ES6 and started my new project using koa.js running on io.js.

In the code below, I am trying to check if there is already another item with the same `url slug`.

But the value of `counter.next().value` always returns a function and hence the function `_slugExists` always returns `true`

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');
let config = require('../../config');

let monk = require('monk');
let wrap = require('co-monk');
let db = monk(config.db);

let _apps = wrap(db.get('apps'));

function _validateApp(app) {
  let slug = app.slug.trim();

  if (!app.name.trim()) {
    throw new Error('App name was not specified.');
  }

  if (!slug) {
    throw new Error('App URL was not specified.');
  }

  if (_slugExists(slug)) {
    throw new Error('Another app with the same URL already exists.');
  }
}

function* _count(filter) {
  yield _apps.count(filter);
}

function _slugExists(slug) {
  let counter = _count({
    slug: slug
  });

  return counter.next().value !== 0;
}

module.exports = {
  list: function*(next) {
    this.status = 200;
    this.body = yield _apps.find({});
  },
  create: function*(next) {
    try {
      let app = this.request.body;
      _validateApp(app);

      this.status = 201;
      this.body = {
        id: yield _apps.insert({
          name: app.name.trim(),
          slug: app.slug.trim(),
          created_at: new Date()
        })
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`[ERROR] ${error.message}`);

      this.status = 500;
      this.body = {
        error: error.message
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a generator function here at all? What do you get if you don't use a generator? What is `_apps.count` supposed to return anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *koa*, which is based on *co*, any async operation must `yield` promises all the way up to koa. You can also `yield` generators, but not iterators. Particularly important is to make sure nested async operations are not left hanging:

```
function* middleware(next) {
  yield Promise.resolve(0); // Yielding a promise. Good.
  yield (function() { return Promise.resolve(0); })(); // Also yielding a promise. Good.

  yield gen(4); // Yielding iterator. NOT GOOD!
  yield gen; // Yielding generator. Good, but no arg.
  yield* gen(4); // Delegating iterator. Good!

  hangingNested(); // Not yielding anything, async is lost. NOT GOOD!
  yield properNested; // Yielding generator with nested delegate, good!
}

function* gen(arg) {
  yield Promise.resolve(1);
  yield Promise.resolve(2);
  yield Promise.resolve(3);
  return arg;
}

function hangingNested() { // not a generator, nothing is yielded outside.
  gen(4); // iterator is lost.
}

function* properNested() {
  yield* gen(4); // Delegating iterator.
}
```

With that in mind, there are various ways you could fix your code, for example:

```
function* _validateApp(app) {
  let slug = app.slug.trim();

  if (!app.name.trim()) {
    throw new Error('App name was not specified.');
  }

  if (!slug) {
    throw new Error('App URL was not specified.');
  }

  if (yield* _slugExists(slug)) {
    throw new Error('Another app with the same URL already exists.');
  }
}

function* _count(filter) {
  return yield _apps.count(filter);
}

function* _slugExists(slug) {
  let counter = yield* _count({
    slug: slug
  });

  return counter !== 0;
}

module.exports = {
  list: function*(next) {
    this.status = 200;
    this.body = yield _apps.find({});
  },
  create: function*(next) {
    try {
      let app = this.request.body;
      yield* _validateApp(app);

      this.status = 201;
      this.body = {
        id: yield _apps.insert({
          name: app.name.trim(),
          slug: app.slug.trim(),
          created_at: new Date()
        })
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(`[ERROR] ${error.message}`);

      this.status = 500;
      this.body = {
        error: error.message
      };
    }
  }
}
```